# Plotting points in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions

Hi guys I'm a bit unsure about what to do for this question I was going to square both sides but then my z's cancel?

Describe and plot the set of points in the complex plane that satisfy the equation $ |z-i|=|z-1| $

Thanks for any help

Comment: See this may be its help you. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://math.bu.edu/people/kost/teaching/spr08/MA412_SelectedHomeworkProblems.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjCz63u56jRAhVJPo8KHae_ASMQFghfMAg&usg=AFQjCNFpqNSK1aUucNbILz7tQAcZ1ZcP8w

Answer (score 1):

**HINT1**:

This is a straight line.

**HINT2**:

$|z-a|$ means the distance from $z$ to $a$.